# Small caps plugin for GIMP

Tags: fonts, plugins, gimp

Is there a way to create small caps in GIMP?

There was a reference to Freetext.org at GIMPTalk, but the plugin doesn't exist. I've installed Freetext on my computer, but don't know how to proceed to make it work with GIMP. Is there a file I should copy to some GIMP directory?

There was also a reference to a small caps plugin, but that doesn't seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeType GIMP plugin [has been officially discontinued](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/projects.html#other), so the only way to type in small caps in the GIMP is to use a small caps font variant such as [Delicious SmallCaps](http://www.exljbris.com/delicious.html):

[image: Small caps in GIMP]

Sadly, there isn't any better solution at this time. While it appears that there was a preliminary version of a Script-Fu script for generating small caps [posted in 2005](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/2940-small-cap-font-effect/page__view__findpost__p__19775), it is [no longer available](https://www.google.com/#q=%22smALL-caps.scm%22+OR+%22and+a+different+size+for+lowercase+characters%22&fp=ce668a3fc9678a40).

Comment: That's sad because I 'need' a specific font and I don't think that's available. Will check and report back.

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 4):

Years later and there still doesn't seem to be an easy way to do it, so I had to kludge together a solution.

Firstly, type out your text in ALL CAPS.

[image: Step 1]

Secondly, select the last letters of each word and change the font size.

[image: Step 2]

And you're done.

[image: Job done]

This is the quickest and easiest way to edit a small amount of text, taking only seconds to do. If you need to do it with a lot of text then I suggest finding a better solution.

Note: The edit box seems to be buggy and loses the selection, or won't resize. It is best to avoid using it if possible. This may just be my version of Gimp however. YMMV.

Gimp 2.8.10

Comment: This is *very* much a kludge, because the weight of the characters will be all wrong vs. real small caps.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [Ken Sharp](https://askubuntu.com/users/170177/ken-sharp/)'s answer there is a more reliable way of doing the same.

Since the edit box seems to still be buggy, you can edit the text the same way as in the mentioned answer by opening the non-buggy `GIMP Text Editor`.

[image: Tool options -> Use editor]

Then in the editor, you proceed as in [the previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/899526/681688), by writing everything in caps, then highlighting the letters you want to be smaller, and changing their size.

Edit: I somehow forgot I'm on an outdated PC and hence on outdated version of GIMP. This answer applies to GIMP 2.8.X and it should be probably taken only as a comment to the answer it's extending.